# NLTK syntax parsing

Tags: python-2.7, syntax, nlp, nltk

I need to parse raw text into syntax tree and find relation between parsed parts  using NLTK without defining special patterns (regex patterns included) and rules as NLTK books proposes.
Is there any opportunity to set this process automatically? 
Or without installing additional tools for integrating Stanford parser it is impossible to do in NLTK?

Comment: Did you have a look at [NLTK's parser API](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.parse.html)? There's quite a number of parsing algorithms, only some of them need additional installations. In any case you'll need to train the parser or find a pretrained model which suits the kind of texts you are working with.

Comment: Great. I'll try some of presented methods. Also I would be grateful for links with additional tutorials (if it possible).
But anyway - thanks a lot!